# Python Faker fake.word(): Filter out profanity

Tags: python, faker

I noticed that when I use the `fake.word()` function with locale set to `'pl_PL'` it sometimes generates a swear word which is not ideal for me. Is there an easy way to force Faker to stop outputting swear words, preferably without having to list all of the swear words myself?

Comment: Must be this huh... https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/lorem/pl_PL/__init__.py#L1965

Comment: I made a pull request that may fix this issue in the future~ https://github.com/joke2k/faker/pull/1746

Comment: I also spotted "Seksualny" once so it's not like "kurwa" is the only inappropriate word on the list. I might just read it all and check but it's not an ideal solution. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not know of a way to remove swear words without typing them out.

One option is to remove the swear words from the word list of the pl_PL lorem `Provider` class.

```py
from faker.providers.lorem.pl_PL import Provider as PLProvider

bad_words = ["kurwa"]
PLProvider.word_list = tuple(word for word in PLProvider.word_list if word not in bad_words)
```

(I use `tuple` here because that is the original type of `word_list`.)

Here is a more complete code example, including an assertion that the bad words are not in the list of possible words.

```py
from faker import Faker

from faker.providers.lorem.pl_PL import Provider as P
bad_words = ["kurwa"]
P.word_list = tuple(word for word in P.word_list if word not in bad_words)
del P

Faker.seed(0)
fake = Faker(locale="pl_PL")

assert "kurwa" not in fake.words(1999, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [original list](https://github.com/joke2k/faker/blob/master/faker/providers/lorem/pl_PL/__init__.py) comes from [wiktionary](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Indeks%3APolski_-_Najpopularniejsze_s%C5%82owa_1-2000), which we can see has been updated since this was made...

We can get the new list ourselves though, using [the API](https://en.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/#/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = 'Indeks%3APolski_-_Najpopularniejsze_s%C5%82owa_1-2000'
method = 'html'
url = f"https://pl.wiktionary.org/api/rest_v1/page/{method}/{page}"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

words = [x['title'] for x in soup.find_all('a')]

print(words[:50])
print(len(words))
```

Output (First 50):

```
['w', 'z', 'być', 'na', 'i', 'do', 'nie', 'który', 'lub', 'to', 'się', 'o', 'mieć', 'coś', 'ten', 'dotyczyć', 'on', 'od', 'co', 'język', 'po', 'że', 'ktoś', 'przez', 'osoba', 'miasto', 'jeden', 'jak', 'za', 'ja', 'rok', 'a', 'bardzo', 'swój', 'dla', 'taki', 'człowiek', 'cecha', 'kobieta', 'mój', 'część', 'związany', 'móc', 'dwa', 'ona', 'związać', 'ze', 'mały', 'jakiś', 'miejsce']
2000
```

---

Then, we could replace the word list like so:

```
from faker.providers.lorem.pl_PL import Provider as PLProvider

PLProvider.word_list = tuple(words)
```

Comment: I have no idea if there are swear words in the new list though... would be worth double checking. I just know that the noted one is no longer on the list.